# XML views Documentation Openui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Where can i see the documentation on XML views?
I find the js API of the interface element but i want a documentation of the property and the content of the pages, lists, tables in XML view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either asking about docu for XML views themselves, in which case see the [XML Views documentation from the SDK](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e3b5323649b44d9a883a6233fb01ee9d.html).

If you're asking about XML view style documentation for individual controls, there isn't anything specific, but the main thing you need to know is that the Properties, Associations, Aggregations and Events listings of the individual control documentation in the API section of the SDK, for example for the [sap.m.Page](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e3b5323649b44d9a883a6233fb01ee9d.html) control, are not particularly JavaScript specific. You might want to read this post "[Mobile Dev Course W3U3 Rewrite - XML Views - An Intro](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-49095)" to give you the context that you need.

Comment: Especially the W3U3 blog series on SCN are of infinite value to any UI5 developer, whether rookie or seasoned. Do you think there's a chance this blog series can be incorporated -- with some alteration -- into the OpenUI5 SDK developer documentation? I'm afraid a significant number of UI5 developers face quite some basic issues of which a lot are addressed with these blogs

Comment: Thanks @Qualiture ... Not sure about incorporating them into the SDK, but perhaps a refresh / renewed highlighting of them somewhere...?